# Need help/suggestions to set max-width of 1st line of h1 to avoid overlapping absolutely positioned element

Tags: css

Below is what my design looks like

[image]

however with a long title, it looks like

[image]

How might I avoid the overlap? I created a fiddle to allow you to work on this (if you prefer)

http://jsfiddle.net/xhp7Q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the comment link first and float it to the right. That way the header will flow around it:

http://jsfiddle.net/xhp7Q/1/

```
.comments {
  float: right;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  color: #000;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `position:absolute;` to `position:relative;` in `.comments` and add `float:right;`

Then move this:

```
<a href="#" class="comments">10</a>
```

To the top of the `p` and `h1` elements:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/xhp7Q/3/)**